# Facebook Login - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently logging users in my app with Facebook like this, I know that version 1 of the FB API is expiring in a few days, here is how I am currently doing it.

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_likes", @"user_location", @"email", @"public_profile", @"user_activities", @"user_interests", @"user_birthday", @"user_friends"];

// Login PFUser using facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
```

Is this going to continue to work?

Answer (score 0):

The `logInWithPermissions` method in PFFacebookUtils is deprecated. With the current version, you should use the `logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` method instead. The parameters for this method are the same.

As for the permissions you're requesting, with the exception of public_profile, you will need to submit your app for review to be able to use the other permissions with v2 of the API.